# Struggling to find the second derivative of this function's first derivative

Tags: calculus, trigonometry, derivatives

So I've found the first derivative of this function but now I have to find the second derivative. I've tried everything but I cannot seem to get it.

Here's the original function: $x = a sec(θ)$, $y = btan(θ)$

Here it is:

> > > $\frac{\operatorname dy}{\operatorname dx}$ = $\frac{\operatorname b}{\operatorname a \!}$ * $csc(θ)$

$a$ and $b$ are constants.

Here are the steps I've tried:

I used the product rule-

Step 1: ($\frac{\operatorname b}{\operatorname a}$) $(-csc(θ) * cot(θ))$ + $(csc(θ))$ * (0)

Step 2: Reduces to: ($\frac{\operatorname b}{\operatorname a}$) * $(-csc(θ) * cot(θ))$

Step 3: Changing the trig functions: ($\frac{\operatorname b}{\operatorname a}$) * ($\frac{\operatorname -1}{\operatorname sin(θ)}$ * $\frac{\operatorname cos(θ)}{\operatorname sin(θ)}$)

Step 4: Simplify: ($\frac{\operatorname b}{\operatorname a}$) * ($\frac{\operatorname -cos(θ)}{\operatorname sin^2(θ)}$)

Now I'm not sure what to do. The question states that I have to prove that the second derivative is:

($\frac{\operatorname d^2y}{\operatorname dθ^2}$) = ($\frac{\operatorname -b}{\operatorname a^2}$) * $csc(θ)$

Thanks very much!

Comment: The original function is...

Comment: Are $b$ and $a$ constants?

Comment: Yes they are constants, sorry for not mentioning that. And I have posted the original question.

Comment: I don't see how the second derivative of y wrt to $\theta$ has a $\csc \theta$ term...is it meant to be x instead?

Comment: My bad, check it out now

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$\begin{align}
\frac{\mathrm d y}{\mathrm d x} & = \frac{\mathrm d (b\tan(\theta))/\mathrm d\theta}{\mathrm d (a\sec(\theta))/\mathrm d\theta}
\\ & = \frac{b \sec^2(\theta)}{a \tan(\theta)\sec(\theta)}
\\ & = \frac{b \csc(\theta)}{a}
\\[2ex]
\frac{\mathrm d ^2 y}{\mathrm d x\,^2} & = \frac{\mathrm d (b\csc(\theta)/a)/\mathrm d\theta}{\mathrm d (a\sec(\theta))/\mathrm d\theta}
\\ & = \frac{-b\cot(\theta)\csc(\theta)/a}{a\tan(\theta)\sec(\theta)}
\\ & = - \frac{b \cot^2(\theta)}{a^2}
\end{align}$

Comment: Thanks this is exactly what I was looking for!

Answer (score 0):

This is the parametric equation of a hyperbola; converting to standard form:

$\frac{x^2}{a^2}-\frac{y^2}{b^2}=1$. You can use implicit differentiation on this and it should go quite smoothly.

__

Alternatively, apply the chain rule: $\frac{\mathrm{d} ^2y}{\mathrm{d} x^2}=\frac{\mathrm{d} }{\mathrm{d} x}(\frac{\mathrm{d} y}{\mathrm{d} x})=\frac{\mathrm{d} }{\mathrm{d} \theta}(\frac{\mathrm{d} y}{\mathrm{d} x}) \cdot\frac{\mathrm{d} \theta}{\mathrm{d} x}$, that should also get the answer for you.

Comment: I don't think that's what I'm supposed to do, he's just asking for me to differentiate the first derivative I have and I am struggling with that.

Comment: I see, I've edited in another way.